# Javascript convert date string to object

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to convert a date in string format to a Date object in JavaScript. The date is coming from the openweathermap.org API, which gives the date string in the following format:

'2018-04-28 09:00:00' or 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'

I know that the JavaScript Date class can take other string formats of dates, but this one returns NaN when I try anything with it. How can I convert a date string, like the one above, and convert it easily to a JavaScript object? Thanks!

Comment: Where did it return `NaN`? Which environment?

Comment: React-native project on Windows 10, running app on Android device.

Comment: Because of the variances in parsing of date strings, it is recommended to always manually parse strings as results are inconsistent, especially across different ECMAScript implementations where strings like "2018-04-28 09:00:00" may be parsed to as NaN, UTC or local timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting `NaN` while directly converting the string to date. You can split the string on spaces, `-` and `:` and then pass the value to date constructor and generate the date object.

```js
const str = `2018-04-28 09:00:00`;
const [date, time] = str.split(' ');
const [year, month, day] = date.split('-');
const [hh, mm, sec] = time.split(':');
const dateObj = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hh, mm, sec);
console.log(dateObj);
```

As pointed out by @RobG, this could also be done using the regex.

```js
const str = `2018-04-28 09:00:00`;
var b = str.split(/\D/);
var date = new Date(b[0],b[1]-1,b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5]);
console.log(date);
```

```js
const str = `2018-04-28 09:00:00`,
      date = new Date(...(str.split(/\D/).map((v,i)=>i==1?--v:v)));
console.log(date);
```

Comment: A lot easier to split on non-digits: `var b = str.split(/\D/)` then `new Date(b[0],b[1]-1,b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5]);` and you're done, and compatible with every implementation ever. ;-)

Comment: Ok, that's working now. Thanks!

Comment: Or if you want to use new stuff and don't care about being inefficient, then `new Date(...(str.split(/\D/).map((v,i)=>i==1?--v:v)))` does the job in less code, but is much less compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Just try `new Date(str)`

```
d = new Date("2018-04-20 09:00:00")
Fri Apr 20 2018 09:00:00 GMT+0800 (Hong Kong Standard Time)
d.getDate()
20
```

ref: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format

Comment: When I do what you suggest and print the result of `d` to the console, it says 'Invalid Date'... Is this date format not recognized by Date?

Comment: That format isn't supported in ECMA-262. Using the built-in parser is not recommended, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: @JohnSeed—parsing of any format other than the one specified in ECMA-262 is implementation dependent. An implementation may decide that is an invalid attempt at the specified format, or it might attempt to parse it to a Date. Both outcomes are consistent with the language specification (e.g. Safari does the former, Chrome the latter, both are based on WebKit).